# jQuery Validation required callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make a form required only if one or both of my checkboxes are selected. I know jQuery validate supports this directly, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

Here's the markup:

```
<form id="text_opt">
<input id="promos" name="promos" type="checkbox" /><label for="promos">Special Promotions</label>
<input id="products" name="products" type="checkbox" /><label for="products">New Products &amp; Services</label>
<div class="mobile-wrap">
    <input id="text_phone" name="text_phone" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone Number" required/>
</div>
<p class="text-msg">*Standard Messaging fees and rates apply</p>
```

Here's the function:

```
function isTextChecked() {
    return jQuery('input#promos').is(':checked') || jQuery('input#products').is(':checked')
}
```

Here's the jQuery Validation call:

```
jQuery('form#text_opt').validate({
    rules: {
        text_number: {
            required: isTextChecked()
        }
    }
});
```

If I call the `isTextChecked()` function in the console it returns true/false as I expect it to, but for some reason the field is required no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up the required rule for the text_number field, but in your form the field name is text_phone. It also has a required attribute, that should be removed as well.

```js
jQuery('form#text_opt').validate({
    rules: {
        text_phone: {
            required: isTextChecked()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: AHA!! After working for awhile I apparently lose my basic reading and comparison skills. Forest for the trees and all that. Thanks so much!